# Porting cudaMallocHost and cudaMemcpyAsync to OpenCL (to use pinned memory)

Tags: c++, cuda, gpu, opencl, gpgpu

I am trying to port some existing CUDA code to OpenCL. The simplified CUDA program does the following:

1. Loads an extremely large (10GB+) file into pinned host memory, allocated via `cudaMallocHost` followed by a `std::fread` from the file into the resulting buffer, done in multiple chunks with allocations of a few hundred MB each.
2. In the main loop, certain chunks are selected, and `cudaMemcpyAsync` is used to copy them from host memory to device memory (pre-allocated with `cudaMalloc`), runs a kernel on them, copying the output result back into host memory.
3. The process repeats indefinitely. Note that the GPU (4GB) does not have enough VRAM to accommodate the entire file in device memory, but after each cycle, all chunks of the file have been processed at least once.

I have a functioning OpenCL implementation, with the differences being:

1. The buffers for the 10GB of host memory are allocated with simple `malloc`s
2. The device buffer is pre-allocated with `clCreateBuffer (CL_MEM_READ_WRITE)` and each chunk is copied to it with `clEnqueueWriteBuffer`, the kernel is called, and the result is obtained with `clEnqueueReadBuffer`

The main problem is the OpenCL version is much slower (50% worse) speeds, due to the host memory not being pinned.

I have tried a few approaches which did not work.

1. Instead of `malloc`, I tried to allocate pinned memory on host with `clCreateBuffer (CL_MEM_ALLOC_HOST_PTR)`. This works, however, it also allocates an equal amount of memory **on device** the moment the host pointer is obtained with `clEnqueueMapBuffer`, which therefore does not permit me to load the entire file due to limited (4GB) device memory.
2. I tried calling `clEnqueueUnmapMemObject` after loading a chunk into RAM with the above method. However, the GPU device memory remains consumed until I call `clReleaseMemObject`, at which point the host memory also gets freed too together with the device memory, and attempting to use the host pointer results in a segfault.
3. I tried a normal `malloc` followed by creating my device buffer with `clCreateBuffer (CL_MEM_USE_HOST_PTR)`, however, this approach does not give pinned memory speeds. It seems that only `CL_MEM_ALLOC_HOST_PTR` will actually result in OpenCL treating the host buffer as pinned memory.
4. I tried manually allocating pinned host memory through windows with `VirtualAlloc(MEM_COMMIT | MEM_RESERVE, PAGE_READWRITE)`, however OpenCL does not recognize that memory as actually being pinned.

In summary: Is there a way for me to use 10gb of pinned host memory in OpenCL, without requiring an equal sized allocation on device memory? Or is there another approach I could try to get the same performance as CUDA?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: If you don't malloc your host buffer with 4k alignment OpenCL will make a copy of it on the host, so you could be copying twice.

Comment: Creating 10 GB of pinned memory when the GPU has only 4 GB seems like a bad idea to me. Available pinned memory can be limited on the system. If you have to pipeline your data to and from the GPU anyway since your dataset is larger than your GPU memory, then why not create smaller `CL_MEM_ALLOC_HOST_PTR` buffers and interleave the `fread` calls with the mapping and computing? That way you can do disk IO and computation in parallel

Comment: @SimonGoater hmm are you suggesting that if the host buffer is 4k aligned, it's possible that it will be treated as pinned memory? Or is additional steps required?

Comment: I'm saying if it isn't 4k aligned it will make a copy that is. It sounds like this could a case for using clCreateSubBuffer() but not sure as I've never used it.

Comment: @Homer512 maybe a little extra clarification: the 10GB of data contain the weights for a large language model which I am running GPU accelerated inference on. Current bottleneck is limited by copying the data between host and device buffers in order to do matrix multiplication on GPU. There is enough system memory to store all tensors of model file fully in DRAM, but not VRAM. I'd imagine disk access would be an order of magnitude slower.

Comment: You could easily check if the 4K alignment is relevant by changing the allocation from `malloc` to `mmap`. `malloc` is always misaligned for large allocations because it takes the first 16 byte for its header